# Laravel: Combining transformed data based on common field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I am transforming some data from a query within my controller and returning it the frontend.  I am getting an array of custom transformed "Orders" with the info I need.  I will be calling this endpoint every few seconds.  I am trying to see if there is a way I can combine the `total` of all the orders that have the same `customer_id`

**Controller**

```
 $orders = Order.where("type", "=", "valid")->get();

   foreach ($orders as $order) {
        $ordersArray[] = [
            'order_id' => $order->id,
            'customer_name' => $order->customer_id),
            'customer_id' => $order->customer_id,
            'total' => $order->total,
        ];
    }

    return [
        'paidOrders'    =>  $ordersArray,
    ];
```

**example of what is returned to the frontend**

```
[
   {order_id: 314, customer_name: "Martin", customer_id: 71, total: 66},
   {order_id: 315, customer_name: "Barry", customer_id: 82, total: 217},
   {order_id: 316, customer_name: "Barry", customer_id: 82, total: 217},
   {order_id: 317, customer_name: "Barry", customer_id: 82, total: 147},
]
```

**example of what I'd like returned -- just combine the total for the same customer**

```
[
   {order_id: 314, customer_name: "Martin", customer_id: 71, total: 66},
   {order_id: ?, customer_name: "Barry", customer_id: 82, total: 581},
]
```

Comment: Yes, you can group them using customer and have an array of order_ids, but that'll change your structure of the output. Any entry would be of the following format `{customer_name: "Martin", customer_id: 71, total: 66, orders: [315, 316, 317]}` . Would this format be okay?. Let me know.

Comment: as Aashish said, you can't have that structure, and it won't have any sense actually, since you are creating a tuple with a 1 to many relation

Comment: I've posted an answer, with the format that the result will produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order Model

```
public function customer(){
   return $this->belongsTo(App\Customer, 'customer_id', 'id');
}
```

Customer Model

```
public function orders(){
   return $this->hasMany(App\Order, 'customer_id', 'id');
}
```

Controller

```
$orders = Order::with('customer')->where('type', 'valid')->get();

$customers = [];

foreach($orders as $order){
   if(!isset($customers[$order->customer_id])){
       $customers[$order->customer_id]['customer_name'] = $order->customer->name;
       $customers[$order->customer_id]['customer_id'] = $order->customer_id;
       $customers[$order->customer_id]['total'] = $order->total;

   }
   else{
       $customers[$order->customer_id]['total'] += $order->total;
   }
   $customers[$order->customer_id]['orders'][] = $order->id;    
}


$result = array_values($customers);
```

Format of the output

```
[
  { customer_name: "Martin", customer_id: 71, total: 66, orders: [314]},
  { customer_name: "Martin", customer_id: 71, total: 581, orders: [315, 316, 317]},
]
```

Comment: @Aashhish  oh this is great, thanks for breaking it down!